# TypeScript WebStorm library sources

Tags: typescript, npm, webstorm, development-environment

I am totally new to TS. Using WebStorm because I am used to JetBrains tooling. From other languages I am used to a workflow where I have some kind of dependency management like `maven` there is option to `download sources` downloads me the library source and when I do some debugging or examining of the library I can dig/explore directly in original source code.

Is there something similar possible in TS or is it impossible by design of `npm` or `ts`? When I download lib like `nestjs` I get only typing files and compiles js files. Is there npm option I missed out to also download TypeScript sources and where debugger can work with it?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that. Initially, when node.js and npm appeared, no one was using compilers/transpilers like TypeScript or Babel, everything was just plain javascript. Whatever was published on [npm](http://npmjs.com) **was** the source.

Over the years, this has changed, but there is still no designated way to publish sources alongside with the code. The only thing that `npm` has is  optional [`repository`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) field in `package.json`, which may contain URL of repository where source code lives. For popular packages, this typically points to github where you can browse the source or clone it.